# Does the Degreaser affect the afterburn damage of the Flare Gun?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-pyro

I know that the Degreaser decreases **its** afterburn damage by 25%, but what about if I have the Degreaser and the Flare Gun (or the Detonator) in my loadout? Is the Flare Gun's afterburn damage reduced by 25%, or is it as normal?

Comment: Forgot to mention this in my last note:  Despite the Degreaser lowering afterburn damage by 25%, due to the numbers involved, it actually ends up being by 33%.  That is, it lowers it from 3 per tick to 2 per tick.

Comment: @Powerlord Why does it say -25% afterburn, then, if its afterburn does 40 damage rather than 60? What does the -25% refer to?

Comment: Damage is only done in whole numbers so Valve rounded it to 2 per tick while normal afterburn is 3 per tick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Each individual weapon's special effect only corresponds to only that weapon, not the entire player loadout. It's just like although the Rocket Jumper has -100% damage penalty, you can still kill other players using Melee or Secondary Weapons (it's one of my favourite loadout - Rocket Jumper, BASE Jumper and Market Gardener).

So yeah, your Flare Gun will still have the same damage and afterburn damage as before.

Comment: For reference, hitting the player with a Flare after setting them on fire with a Degreaser will do any immediate damage (90, 41, 30, or 15 depending on which flare gun) and then start dealing the 3 per half second afterburn.

Comment: @Powerlord What about if I first flare them, and **then** use my Degreaser on them? What will be the afterburn after I use my Degreaser (assuming I Degreased them immediately after shooting a flare at them)?

Comment: @alexqwx Afterburn is based on whatever the last damage source was... so if you Degreaser them after Flare Gun, it drops down to 2 damage per half second.  Incidentally, afterburn from crits is 1 damage higher than normal (4 for most items, 3 for degreaser).

Comment: Ah, so, instead of stacking, the afterburn damaged just gets replaced by the most recent fire-based weapon used (in which case I should always Degrease, then shoot a flare)?